# Django - MongoDB - referring to wrong model

Tags: django, mongodb

I have 3 models, A, B and C.

Model C have 2 reference fields, one is pointing to A and another to B. There are 3  update APIs, for each of the model tables.

There is a 4th API that will retrieve data from table C and related data in table A and B.

Sometimes during fetching the data in 4th API, we face issue where the variable pointing to model B is said to be pointing to model A and hence fail to get the field which is in B and not in A. This sometimes happen for variable pointing to model A as well.

This happen on and off and it get resolved on its own.

I am not sure where to start looking for the issue.

Can someone please help me?

EDIT 1:
Here is the basic model example

```
class A(models.Model):
    short_name = fields.StringField()

class B(models.Model):
    description = fields.StringField()

class C(models.Model):
    name = fields.StringField()
    short_name_id = fields.ReferenceField(A)
    desc_id = fields.ReferenceField(B)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's the text which would be displayed from the typical close reason that a "why does my code ( not included in the question ) not do what I want?" question. I usually drop this message to new accounts as a pre-warning to take action before the question is closed. Your account has been active for enough years that you should understand this is off-topic and not a way to ask a question by now, or at least have received that message before. Please read the MCVE page and follow it. A **"small"** sample of code to reproduce the problem. **Not** your whole application code.

Comment: @NeilLunn, that is the problem. I am not able to pinpoint the issue. the code is working fine for fetching rows of model C. But sometimes I get the error that short_name_id is pointing to B and hence not able to retrieve description field.

Comment: We cannot debug your whole application, nor can we read minds. You need to be able to show something that "reproduces the problem" in order for anyone to give input on it. That's just how the system works here. Just telling you how it is, and you can do with that what you will.

Comment: @NeilLunn I understand that but please try to understand that if I can reproduce the problem, I can resolve it as well. There is nothing else in this application, only this code. There is no need to be rude, I know you cannot read my mind and if a code is not working, I have to add a snippet. But this is working but it is giving intermittent issue for no reason and resolving on its own.